understanding horocyles
I am independently studying horocycle flow and accidently I understood that horocycles are something in hyperbolic geometry, so I need a reference to know how to calculates distances in them, what exactly are horocycles and so on.
Could anyone help me in this please?

Have you tried starting from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horocycle?

It seems that you are trying to learn hyperbolic geometry without reading a textbook: this is a mistake. Consider reading, say, Anderson's book on hyperbolic geometry, before reading about translational surfaces.

@MoisheKohan but this book does not contain horocyles, I looked at it before posting this question here

Yes, it does, look on page 67.

oh thank you, my bad, I should have looked thoroughly @MoisheKohan

@MaikPickl thank you very much!
